# Are which+ noun and whose nouns are acceptable in English free relatives?

Tags: grammar, american-english, questions, relative-clauses

I am curious if the following two sentences are acceptable in English.

a. He read which books she read.

b. I am sure that my dad will pay for whose cars I damage.

Comment: You should include why you think these might/might not be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering because they are good in questions. Which books does she read? and Whose cars did you damage? It seems to me that they are kind of off when they are objects. I just wanna confirm my intuitions:)

Comment: Interrogative and relative clauses follow very different rules.

Comment: *I am curious if the following two sentences are acceptable in English.* They are not: a. *He read which**ever** books she read.*  b. *I am sure that my dad will pay for who**ever's** cars I damage.*

Comment: You need "He read whichever books she read" and "I am sure that my dad will pay for whosever cars I damage". The use of "whosever" is questionable for some speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example a seems grammatical, but sounds weird. A literal interpretation of it is that there's a written list of books that she read, and he read that list.

If the intent was that he read the same books that she read, it should use "whichever" rather than "which", or more simply

> He read the books she read.

Example b is simply wrong. If you want to say that he'll pay the owners of the cars you damage, it should be

> I'm sure my dad will pay those whose cars I damage.

"those" is the direct object of "pay", and "whose cars I damage" is a prepositional phrase defining them.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with what you say. I'd say that a. is ungrammatical, though I agree that "He read whichever books she read" is fine and the correct sentence here. In b, "whose cars I damage" is not a PP, but an NP, but the correct version is "I am sure that my dad will pay for whosever cars I damage".

Comment: Isn't the NP "those whose ...". And I was going to suggest something like your last sentence, but it was going to be "pay whoevers' cars ..." and that sounded clumsy.